Unzipping a file with a very long file name
Windows 11 home.
I have a .zip file that has a file inside with the path (relative to the top of the .zip file) SitePlansTemp\FATR2023TE4W1F0052UG\Poly{[6-[(1,1,3,3-tetramethylbutyl)amino]-1,3,5-triazine-2,4-diyl][(2,2,6,6-tetramethyl-4-piperidyl)imino]-1,6-hexanediyl[(2,2,6,6-tetramethyl-4-piperidyl)imino]} Light Stabilizer (Upload_Index_1844232).pdf
(File name is 206 characters, relative path in .zip file is 206 + 35 = 241 characters.)
I can unzip this file to C:\a\ (which adds 5 characters to the path, for a total of 246) but get a "path to long" error when trying to unzip to C:\Users\Public\Documents\CAMEO Data Manager 4.3.0 Data\tmp\unzip\ (which adds 66 characters to the path, for a total of 301).
All of this makes sense with the Windows 260 character path limit.
(I also get the same error when trying to unzip to that second directory programmatically using the C miniz library.)
What I don't understand is:

I am able to drag-and-drop this file out of the .zip file into the (pre-existing) folder C:\Users\Public\Documents\CAMEO Data Manager 4.3.0 Data\tmp\unzip\SitePlansTemp\FATR2023TE4W1F0052UG\ and it works fine. How does that work? I see stuff about editing a registry value to allow long paths on Windows, but I did no such edit.

I am able to use 7zip to unzip the original file to C:\Users\Public\Documents\CAMEO Data Manager 4.3.0 Data\tmp\unzip\ (what I was originally trying to do with Windows Explorer) and it works. What could 7zip be doing differently? And: is there a library that does what 7zip is doing (and working) instead of what miniz is doing (and failing)?



Please tell us how you do the "I can unzip this file to C:\a" step - how is it different from the "drag-and-drop this file out of the .zip file" method?

I meant: I can unzip the entire file to C:\a\ using Windows Explorer's Extract All. The drag-and-drop is going into the .zip file in Windows Explorer (without unzipping it), and dragging just that one file to the destination.

As pure speculation, it could be that some parts of Windows 11 have not yet been updated to use long file names. And (not speculation) 7-Zip has been updated appropriately.

Incidentally, you might want to use CAS Registry Numbers instead of the full names.

Thanks. Yeah, I don't have control of the files names, which is the problem.

As you've found that you can work around the problem by using 7-Zip, is there still a problem you'd like us to address, or did you just want to know why Windows was being (sadly) inadequate?

Thanks. Well, I'm trying to do this unzip programmatically. I see that 7zip is open source so I may try to use that code. I am currently using miniz. I also have the option of using the zip library in POCO. It would be useful to know what the key things 7zip is doing to make it work, and perhaps I could make those changes in miniz or find another library that does that stuff. But this is all stuff I can research in the code.

7-Zip has bothj the GUI file manager, 7zFM.exe, and 7z.exe, the consol app, which should make the task easier. That said, you could include in the batch file a line that automatically makes the filename shorter, or refer to the file using wold cards, e.g., Poly{[6-[(1,1,3,3-tetramethylbutyl)amino]*.zip

In case it helps someone, the Poco decompress() function also handles long paths in Windows properly. I am now using that in my program, not the 7zip library, which is badly documented.
Also, the long path trick that 7zip must be using to handle long paths correctly is: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70422427/support-for-long-paths-using-prefix
